# Word Add-in - How to read custom property and return the value?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office365api

I succeeded to read a custom property from Word document with this function:

```
getPropertyValue() {
  Word.run(function(context) {
    var someProperty = context.document.properties.customProperties.getItemOrNullObject("SomeProperty");
    context.load(someProperty);
    return context.sync()
      .then(function () {
        if (someProperty.isNullObject) {
          console.log("someProperty not found");
        }
        else {
          console.log("+++++ someProperty is " + someProperty.value);
          return someProperty.value;
        }
      })
    });
  return '';
}

render() {
  var someProp = this.getPropertyValue();
  return (
    <Button className='ms-welcome__action' buttonType={ButtonType.hero}
            iconProps={{ iconName: 'ChevronRight' }}
            onClick={ () => {
              if (someProp) {
                this.setState({ name: 'John', address: 'NYC', someProperty: someProp });
              } else {
                this.setState({ name: 'John', address: 'NYC' }); 
                                        }
             }}>Save</Button>
  )
}
```

It prints the correct property value to JavaScript console. However, the function always returns an empty string. It never returns the property value.

How should I modify the function to return the property value?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is from `context.load(someProperty)`. it could work if you change it to

```
someProperty.load("key, value");
```

You can find my gist at https://gist.github.com/lumine2008/4fc0b40b9b5798d9df93712fbe7fd8f3

Comment: I tried with `someProperty.load("key, value");` and `someProperty.load("value");`, but the function still returns an empty string.

Comment: I just added the gist, it works in my side, could you try it in your side?

Comment: no doubt the gist works, but in my case the return value of the `getPropertyValue()` function should be set to `this.state.someProperty`. When I put the `getPropertyValue()` function to async scope, there is a compiler error: Argument of type '{ name: string; address: string; someProperty: Promise<string>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AppState | ((prevState: Readonly<AppState>, props: Readonly<AppProps>)

Comment: Could you please try my gist and see if you can get the property correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I use `self.setState({ someProperty: someProperty.value });` to pass the property value so that I can use it in `this.state.someProperty`.

```
getPropertyValue() {
  var self = this;
  Word.run(function(context) {
    var someProperty = context.document.properties.customProperties.getItemOrNullObject("SomeProperty");
    context.load(someProperty);
    return context.sync()
      .then(function () {
        if (someProperty.isNullObject) {
          console.log("someProperty not found");
        }
        else {
          console.log("+++++ someProperty is " + someProperty.value);
          self.setState({ someProperty: someProperty.value });
          return someProperty.value;
        }
      })
    });
  return '';
}

render() {
  this.getPropertyValue();
  return (
    <Button className='ms-welcome__action' buttonType={ButtonType.hero}
            iconProps={{ iconName: 'ChevronRight' }}
            onClick={ () => {
              if (this.state.someProperty) {
                this.setState({ name: 'John', address: 'NYC' });
              } else {
                this.setState({ name: 'John', address: 'NYC' }); 
              }
             }}>Save</Button>
  )
}
```